# Angular rootScope not visible in template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I change the class on my `<body>` element, depending on which `$state` my website is currently showing.

I say `<body class="{{specialClass}}">`, where `specialClass` is a variable of `$rootScope`. This variable is set in `run` block of my main app module:

```
angular.module("main", [dependencies])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, currentState){
        switch (currentState.name) {
            case "about":
                console.log("I'm on landing page, set specialClass in $rootScope");
                $rootScope.specialClass = 'landing-page';
                break;
            default:
                $rootScope.specialClass = '';
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

For some reason, my template doesn't see `specialClass` variable, so the class attribute is empty. At the same time, `"I'm on landing page, set specialClass in $rootScope"` shows up.

What's wrong?

My full `index.html` template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My project</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="main" class="{{specialClass}}">
        <ui-view>
            This is my application.
        </ui-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's even more crazy is when I serve frontend in development with Webpack dev server, it works ok, the class is switched. But when I serve this in production with Django, it is not. Console output is present in both cases.

Comment: Try use ng-class directive

Comment: in which tag you bootstrap your application?? the `ngApp` directive must contain the body tag.

Comment: Where is that template?

Comment: @Hitmands Good point. `ngApp` directive is applied to the body tag. It is in fact: `<body ng-app="main" class="{{specialClass}}">`.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse well, the template is generated by Webpack and put into the templates folder of Django backend. I've edited the question and added it. Webpack inserts scripts and styles into that template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) about array syntax, I try this in my own app:

```
(() =>
{
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [/**'ng-routing'**/])
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
    {
        // $rootScope.specialClass = ''; // no need, since an empty string is falsy as well as undefined OR null
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, currentState)
        {
            switch (currentState.name)
            {
                case "about":
                    $rootScope.specialClass = 'landing-page';
                    break;
            }
        });
    }]);
})();
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app" ng-cloak ng-strict-di>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{app.title}}</title>
        <script src="web/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="web/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="web/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-class="[specialClass]">
    </body>
</html>
```